# Kafka Strimzi on AKS: How to config PLAIN listeners when external listeners(ScramSha512, TLS encryption) & ACL is already configured

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

I have already configured the external listeners and ACL as it follows (those are functional)

```
listeners:
 plain: {}
 external:
  type: loadbalancer
  tls: true
  authentication:
   type: scram-sha-512
authorization:
 type: simple
```

This is hosted on a AKS cluster. Consuming from on prem it does work already and also producing from inside the cluster but with *publicIP:9094* as bootstrapServers.

I would like to add a producer inside the cluster and use 9092 port (like this *`BootstrapServers = "my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092"`*, I suppose) with minumun necessary effort (even without ACL if possible, without any authentication, without any encryption).

What would recommend?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SO thanks to Jakub from Strimzi https://github.com/scholzj, this is the minimal config

```
listeners:
  plain:
    authentication:
      type: scram-sha-512
  external:
    type: loadbalancer
    tls: true
    authentication:
      type: scram-sha-512
authorization:
  type: simple
```

And the C# client would look like this

```
        var conf = new ProducerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = "my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092",
            SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslPlaintext,
            SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.ScramSha512,
            SaslUsername = "admin",
            SaslPassword = "xxx",
        };
```

Explanation would be:

> Kafka has only one authorizer configuration for the whole cluster. So
> it is either on or off for all listeners. The plain listener is
> without encryption, but if you need authorization for the external
> listener, you will need enable authentication there (since without
> authentication the authorization would deny everything).